# django.jQuery $ is not a function message

Tags: jquery, django, python-3.x, django-admin

in my django project i would to clean a field value based on an event in another field on a django admin add/edit form.
i insert in the admin/change_form.html my call to js :

```
{{ block.super }}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/admin.js' %}"></script>
    {{ media }}
{% endblock %}
```

then my admin.js:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("select[name='main_id']").change(function() {
            $("select['test_id']").val('');
        });
    });
})(django.jQuery);
```

but when i open my django-admin page in console i get:

> Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

on the "$(document).ready(function() {" line.

Someone can help me with this error?

So many thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the class Media in your admin.py file like this:

```
class Media:
    js = (
        '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js',  # jquery
        'js/admin.js',       # project static folder
    )
```

Comment: The next (most upvoted btw) answer is the one, jQuery is already loaded, no need to load it twice.

Answer (score 44):

**Instead of adding second copy of jQuery just make sure your JS is executed after `djagno.jQuery` is defined.**

You can solve this issue by simply wrapping your JS in with an event listener that fires when the `window` has loaded.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    (function($) {
        $("select[name='main_id']").change(function() {
            $("select['test_id']").val('');
        });
    })(django.jQuery);
});
```

The `"load"` event is fired when the `window`, as you might have guessed, loads. `window.addEventListener()` simply registers an event listener that executes the contents of the anonymous function when the event fires. This happens after all resources have loaded.

Because the `window` `"load"` event will fire after `$(document).ready()` you don't need that anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Let's try to insert jQuery script before?

```
{{ block.super }}
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous" defer></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/admin.js' %}" defer></script>
    {{ media }}
{% endblock %}
```